# How to join large subset of data with smaller subset data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have three tables in SQL Server

- `TABLE_A` - contains 500 rows
- `TABLE_B` - contains 1 million rows
- `TABLE_C` - contains 1 million rows

I want to select the rows from `TABLE_B` and `TABLE_C` join with `TABLE_A` based on a row number position from `TABLE_B` and `TABLE_C` tables.

Below is my sample query:

```
SELECT TOP (50), *
INTO ##tempResult
FROM TABLE_A
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT *
     FROM 
         (SELECT 
              memberID,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TABLE_A.member_id ORDER BY TABLE_A EM.UTupdateDate DESC) AS rowNum,
          FROM 
              TABLE_B
          JOIN 
              TABLE_C ON TABLE_B.memberID = TABLE_C.memberID
         )
    ) AS TABLE_subset
WHERE 
    TABLE_subset.rowNum <=2
) AS TABLE_INC ON TABLE_A.memberID = TABLE_INC.memberID
WHERE TABLE_A.colA = 'XYZ'
```

Here the `TABLE_subset` is joining entire records in `TABLE_B` and `TABLE_C`, but I want to join only the top 50 records with `TABLE_A`.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Think you are showing too many brackets... they don't match.

Comment: I think there may be some issues with the redaction/translation process you've used to construct your example from your actual code. I might be missing something, but the `row__number()` calculation in the sub-select is referencing columns from TableA which it doesn't have any reference to. That might be related to the issue that @DaleK brought up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question and query doesn't match exactly, but CROSS APPLY is probably your friend here.
The general idea is:

```sql
select TOP 50 *
from tableA a
CROSS APPLY (
   SELECT TOP 2 b.id, c.otherid
   from tableB b
   inner join tableC c
     ON c.id = b.id
   where b.id = a.id -- Here you match field between A and B
   order by b.date DESC -- order by something
) data
```

Now just need to adapt to your needs